# How to use multithreading when web-scraping using requests

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, python-requests, pool

The following is the code I use to scrape my data and save it as a pickle file. For the links where an error is returned the code simply records the url and appends it in another list so that I can scrape them again.

```
data= []
failed_url = []
error =[]
start = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )

# list_url is a list containing all urls
for path in list_url:
    try:
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        filters = [dict(source_location="petitions_browse")]
        params = dict(q=json.dumps(dict(filters=filters)))
        result = requests.get(url=path,params=params)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        data_dict = result.json()

        data.append({
            'Data_dict': data_dict,
            'id': data_dict['id'],
            'title': data_dict['title'],
            'text':  data_dict['description'],
            'Topic': data_dict['topic'],
            'Topic_alt': data_dict['tags'][0]['name'],
            'Created_date': data_dict['created_at'].split("T")[0],
            'Created_time': data_dict['created_at'].split("T")[1],
            })
        time.sleep(5)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        error.append(e)
        failed_url.append(path)
        continue
    
    if len(data)%50 == 0:
        pickle.dump(data, open("data_checkpoint"+".pkl", "wb"))
        
pickle.dump(data, open("data"+".pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(failed_url, open("failed_url"+".pkl", "wb"))
end = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print('start time:', start, 'end time:', end)
print('Failed Links:', failed_url)
```

I adapt it for multiprocessing using the following code:

```
def get_data(url):
    try:
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        filters = [dict(source_location="petitions_browse")]
        params = dict(q=json.dumps(dict(filters=filters)))
        result = requests.get(url=url,params=params)
        data_dict = result.json()
        return{
            'Data_dict': data_dict,
            'id': data_dict['id'],
            'title': data_dict['title'],
            'text':  data_dict['description'],
            'Topic': data_dict['topic'],
            'Topic_alt': data_dict['tags'][0]['name'],
            'Created_date': data_dict['created_at'].split("T")[0],
            'Created_time': data_dict['created_at'].split("T")[1],
            
            }
        #time.sleep(5)        
     except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        try:
            return {'Data_dict': data_dict}
        except Exception as c:
            return("failed_url", path)
        #continue
```

```
with Pool(10) as pool:
    result = pool.map(get_data, url_list)
    print(result)

failed_url,data=[],[]
for res in result:
    if isinstance(res,tuple):
        failed_url.append(res[1])
    else:
        data.append(res)
        
pickle.dump(data, open("data"+".pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(failed_url, open("failed_url_test"+".pkl", "wb"))
```

This adaptation does not seem to be running. For a small number of links it keeps running for a long time and thus it seems there is a problem with it because for the same number of links the code without multithreading is faster.

Comment: Does `map` ever return? "does not seem to be running" is a little vague.

Comment: I will recommend to use the ```scrapy``` framework, is easy to use and you can set it up to use mt requests

Comment: If you really want to achieve concurrency while making requests, I recommend `aiohttp`. It uses `asyncio` under the hood, and it'll likely be faster than multi-threading and multi-processing with `requests`.

Docs: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/

Comment: Also note that you're doing a broad catch of all `Exeption`s, which is poor. In this case, if any of the first four lines in the function raise an exception, the `except` block will be entered, then `data_dict` will raise a `NameError` because it won't have been set yet. Since you don't mention an error, that doesn't seem to be the problem here. I'd still be aware of that though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I edited the catch of Exception. I guess this should fix what you are talking about!

Comment: @stackauth_11011 That fixes the immediate problem. It's better though to only wrap in a `try` the code that you want caught for a particular reason. I don't think you should even allow for the possibility of `data_dict` being needed before it's been assigned. Also, don't catch `Exception`. Catch the specific exception subclass that you want to deal with. Catching all exceptions leads to unrelated errors being hidden which interferes with debugging.